# AngularJS ng-if generating error when used to load image

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting a not found error when I load an icon using the following AngularJS HTML markup (everything works graphically though):

```
<div class="page-icon" ng-if="icon != null">
    <img src="{{icon}}">
</div>
```

Which generates the following not found error:

```
GET http://localhost/%7B%7Bicon%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ng-src` attribute instead.

```
<div class="page-icon" ng-if="icon != null">
    <img ng-src="{{icon}}">
</div>
```

**Why does this happen?**
Basically, because before angular even kicks in, the browser will look at the DOM and find a image with the `src` with a value of `{{icon}}`. And so it will try to load an image from `http://localhost/{{icon}}`. Of course, it will find none.

After AngularJs has done it's work, the `src` will be populated with the correct value and the image will be loaded and presented.

What `ng-src` does is waiting for the variable `icon` to have a value at least once and only then setting the value for the real attribute `src`. This means that only then does the browser know that is has an image to load, and it already has the correct URL.